# Tracing in Dynamics AX 2012 AOS during loadtest

Tags: performance-testing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, trace

I'm currently preparing a loadtest on a dynamics AX application. We're exploring the possibilities for enabling tracing on the AOS during the loadtest. I'm worried the trace might impact the performance of the server, therefore influencing the test results.

Is it possible to do tracing during a load test without influencing the results?

Comment: According to [Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3](https://books.google.com/books?id=yQ0bBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA501&ots=QMDvmkivIt&dq=dynamics%20ax%20trace%20overhead%20inside&pg=PA501#v=onepage&q=dynamics%20ax%20trace%20overhead%20inside&f=false), the overhead by tracing is about 4%.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that if you turn on AX tracing (e.g., either by editing the [Ax32Serv.exe.config](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2014/06/29/instrumentation-and-tracing) or [using the WCF tracing](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/66225)), you will create a performance impact under load (and also end up with some huge logs). FH-Inway's comment that tracing causes only 4% overhead might be right (depends on the load), but under load the real problem is the gigabytes of logs that you get from just one minute of turning them on. This is also true if you use the Trace Parser method of monitoring.

If you are failing under load, you should also be able to find exception messages returned to you in the failed request.

You can also view all the exceptions AX throws through the AOS GUI (see the System--> Exceptions item in the GUI) or you can query AX's exception table directly using a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS theCount ,EXCEPTION ,theDESCRIPTION 
FROM ( 
SELECT SE.CREATEDDATETIME ,SE.EXCEPTION ,SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), SE.DESCRIPTION), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' '), (CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)), ' '), CHAR(32), ' '), 1, 250) AS theDESCRIPTION 
FROM SYSEXCEPTIONTABLE SE 
LEFT JOIN AIFEXCEPTIONMAP T2 ON (SE.RECID = T2.EXCEPTIONID) 
LEFT JOIN PARTITIONS T3 ON (SE.DATAPARTITION = T3.RECID) 
WHERE SE.CREATEDDATETIME > '2015-12-15 02:25:50' ) AS InnerS 
--where theDESCRIPTION like '%deadlock%' 
GROUP BY Exception ,theDESCRIPTION 
ORDER BY theCount DESC
```

You can isolate your issue to the SQL tier or the AOS tier in AX by using the SQL Server based Performance Analyzer for Dynamics AX. DynPerf has almost no perf impact.

If you are under load my suggestion would be to start with Perf Analyzer (DynPerf), or use SQL Server's own DMVs to get an idea of what queries are performing poorly, then find the specific user action that the query relates to.

Finally, AX Perfmon counters can give you some information about what is happening.

The different options for monitoring AX are listed in the TechNet article "Tools for monitoring performance [AX 2012]". As you can see there is a plethora of monitoring options in AX. Just as much as in any other system.

If you are getting a lot of exceptions, run each scenario in the load test in isolation until you find the test and the data that throws the exception.

Load testing is a great way to figure out how you are going to monitor and troubleshoot problems in production. If you can't do it in the load test, how will you do it when real users are having problems?

You do not say how you are loading they system. Are you going through the AIF? You also do not state the reasons you want to do the tracing. Is it merely to monitor response time? If you are using Visual Studio load tools and you have properly wrapped your requests with Begin and End.Timer() methods, your load tool will collect response times for you.

Comment: If you are going through an AIF port, another option  is to turn on one of the levels of logging on the port see "Troubleshooting options for Integration Ports" article on TechNet. You can also turn on Document Loggging; see the TechNet article "View the Document Log"

Comment: The load will be a combination of placing messages directly on inbound queues, running batchjobs to process the data from these messages, and sending requests to a few SOAP webservices. The response times of the webservices will be measured by Jmeter (amongst other things). I'm planning to use a combination perfmon counters and Dynperf, if necessary we can repeat (parts of) the test to zoom in on other areas. Thanks for your very informative reply.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to do tracing during a load test without influencing the results?"

Not really. If it didn't have a performance impact, tracing would always be on. The mere act of tracing is causing additional work, so it must affect the results.

If you're performance testing against a baseline system with the same load test, you could turn tracing on in both environments, somewhat nullifying the performance against both.